# Read the content of web part

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, powershell

I have content editor,script editor, image viewer etc.. part on share point homepage. I am able to read the web part properties. Now i want to read the content or values of that web part using power shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PnP for this. First you can get list of web parts on the page, then get the property of the web part you need using Get-PnPWebPart and Get-PnPWebPartProperty

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpwebpartproperty?view=sharepoint-ps

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpwebpart?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: links are dead.  fyi

Answer (score 0):

Demo:

```
$completeUrl="http://sp:6912"
$SPweb = Get-SPWeb($completeUrl)

$wpMngr = $SPweb.GetLimitedWebPartManager("SitePages/testttt.aspx",[System.Web.UI.WebControls.Webparts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared); #you could change the page
foreach($wp in $wpMngr.WebParts)
{ 
Write-Host $wp
Write-Host $wp.Content
Write-Host $wp.ImageLink
Write-Host "------------"
}
$SPweb.Dispose()
```

For different web part,we need to use different attribute to get the content.

Script Editor: `$wp.Content`

Image Viewer: `$wp.ImageLink`

Content Editor: `$wp.ContentLink` (As I test ,if we write code in cewp directly, we can not get the value)

Comment: For webpart Zone, ZoneId, ZoneIndex , how to add in the above code.

Comment: I just find Zone and ZoneIndex in the properties,just use $wp.Zone and $wp.ZoneIndex